# Subsetting data frame by multiple criteria using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following code:

```
library(data.table)
#read in data
data = fread("C:/Users/lar2/Desktop/Science/test.tsv")
```

I know how to subset the data frame using one element:

```
data_sub = data[data$V1==1]
```

Suppose I have a list:

```
list = c(1,2,3,4,1,55,66)
```

Pseudocode:

```
data_sub = data[data$V1 in list]
```

How do I subset the data frame to only include rows where data$V1 is in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
data[V1 %in% list]
```

or we can `set` the 'key' as 'V1'

```
setkey(data, 'V1')[list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative using dplyr:

```
list = c(1,2,3,4,1,55,66)

filter(data, list)
```